# Filling in gaps for outlines

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl

I'm using an algorithm to generate quads. These become outlines. The algorithm is:

```
 void OGLENGINEFUNCTIONS::GenerateLinePoly(const std::vector<std::vector<GLdouble>> &input,
     std::vector<GLfloat> &output, int width)
 {

     output.clear();
     if(input.size() < 2)
     {
         return;
     }
     int temp;
     float dirlen;
     float perplen;
     POINTFLOAT start;
     POINTFLOAT end;
     POINTFLOAT dir;
     POINTFLOAT ndir;
     POINTFLOAT perp;
     POINTFLOAT nperp;

     POINTFLOAT perpoffset;
     POINTFLOAT diroffset;

     POINTFLOAT p0, p1, p2, p3;

     for(unsigned int i = 0; i < input.size() - 1; ++i)
     {

         start.x = static_cast<float>(input[i][0]);
         start.y = static_cast<float>(input[i][1]);

         end.x = static_cast<float>(input[i + 1][0]);
         end.y = static_cast<float>(input[i + 1][1]);

         dir.x = end.x - start.x;
         dir.y = end.y - start.y;

         dirlen = sqrt((dir.x * dir.x) + (dir.y * dir.y));

         ndir.x = static_cast<float>(dir.x * 1.0 / dirlen);
         ndir.y = static_cast<float>(dir.y * 1.0 / dirlen);

         perp.x = dir.y;
         perp.y = -dir.x;

         perplen = sqrt((perp.x * perp.x) + (perp.y * perp.y));

         nperp.x = static_cast<float>(perp.x * 1.0 / perplen);
         nperp.y = static_cast<float>(perp.y * 1.0 / perplen);

         perpoffset.x = static_cast<float>(nperp.x * width * 0.5);
         perpoffset.y = static_cast<float>(nperp.y * width * 0.5);

         diroffset.x = static_cast<float>(ndir.x * 0 * 0.5);
         diroffset.y = static_cast<float>(ndir.y * 0 * 0.5);

            // p0 = start + perpoffset - diroffset
             //p1 = start - perpoffset - diroffset
             //p2 = end + perpoffset + diroffset
            // p3 = end - perpoffset + diroffset 

         p0.x = start.x + perpoffset.x - diroffset.x;
         p0.y = start.y + perpoffset.y - diroffset.y;

         p1.x = start.x - perpoffset.x - diroffset.x;
         p1.y = start.y - perpoffset.y - diroffset.y;

             p2.x = end.x + perpoffset.x + diroffset.x;
             p2.y = end.y + perpoffset.y + diroffset.y;

             p3.x = end.x - perpoffset.x + diroffset.x;
             p3.y = end.y - perpoffset.y + diroffset.y;




         output.push_back(p2.x);
         output.push_back(p2.y);
         output.push_back(p0.x);
         output.push_back(p0.y);
         output.push_back(p1.x);
         output.push_back(p1.y);
         output.push_back(p3.x);
         output.push_back(p3.y);

     }
 }
```

The problem is that there are then gaps as seen here:
http://img816.imageshack.us/img816/2882/eeekkk.png

There must be a way to fix this. I see a pattern but I just cant figure it out. There must be a way to fill the missing inbetweens.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039026/edges-on-polygon-outlines-not-always-correct/3058978#3058978).

Add a triangle connecting the "outside" (check the sign of the 2D '[cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan#Algorithm)') vertexes  with the center joint vertex.

If you want to get fancier you can do a [2D slerp](http://number-none.com/product/Understanding%20Slerp,%20Then%20Not%20Using%20It/) to get a more rounded outer join, though this does cost correspondingly more triangles.

Also, if you're going to use lines that wide and so finely subdivided you might try [simplifying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) them first to reduce overdraw/polycount.