# SDL: Performance SPriG vs SDL_gfx

Tags: performance, sdl, polygon

I need to draw a polygon with thick lines. Now I have two possibilities:

- Draw them with the library [SPriG](http://code.bluedinosaurs.com), which provides line thickness.
- Split up the polygon in all it lines and draw them as polygons with a modified thickness <sub>(like explained in [this tutorial](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0260.html) (1 tutorial on the page).)</sub> with the SDL_gfx library.

I'm not sure about the performance of SPriG. SDL_gfx will be the fastest I guess.
Did you ever tried this, or simply "do you know the quality of SPrig"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like SPriG just [draws a circle](http://code.google.com/p/sprig/source/browse/trunk/SPG_primitives.c#1329) at each pixel along a line to give it thickness.  For wide lines you're looking at quite a bit of overdraw.

[I'd do it a bit differently.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039026/edges-on-polygon-outlines-not-always-correct/3058978#3058978)  It may or may not be faster depending on how triangle rasterization compares to per-pixel circle overdraw.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use one of them. Just make use use of OpenGL and call: `glLineWidth(3.6f);`