# Game Dev - Making low res geometric shapes

Tags: geometry, 2d, game-engine

I've used two 2d game frameworks (SpriteKit and Corona SDK) and have not found a way to programmatically create low res 2d shapes. They seem to be more centered on using sprites or image files.

For an example look at eliss infinity https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuKGJyJZY7s

How is something like this done?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Usually, an artist creates such assets.

Comment: In the case of eliss all the art is created programmatically. Watch the trailer

Comment: What tells you that it is created programmatically? I'm pretty sure that there is quite some artistic work involved. Even if the results of the artist are post-processed.

Comment: The developer said so and it's obvious while playing

Comment: Maybe [Shapes — Paths, Fills, Strokes](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/path.html) will help you.

Comment: looks like simple 2D vector graphics +/- some pixel art for filling space. Reminds me on the old days  ZX-Spectrum and ATARI ... for the pixelation see [OpenGL Scale Single Pixel Line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654398/2521214)