# How to make low-res graphics with opengl?

Tags: opengl

I am writing using opengl in C and I want to make oldschool style graphics – like Star Fox for SNES. So I plan to have a 2D array (I'll figure out how, just talking pseudocode for now) of fragments that will represent the lower resolution (you can imagine just containing rbg color info). So I'm going to be writing my own code that makes the 3D world and rasterizes it into this 2D array (might try to get the GPU to help there). Does this even make sense? Are there better ways to make low-res 2D graphics using OpenGL?

Comment: You want to write a rasterizer in opengl although rasterization is already part of the opengl graphics pipeline?

Comment: That's why I'm asking. Seems weird, but seeing as how I want to get very low-res, I don't see what else to do.

Comment: @Steven2163712: If you want low-res results, render at *low resolutions*.

Comment: But I don't get to decide the resolution of the user's screen.

Comment: But you get to decide the resolution of your framebuffer.

Comment: see duplicate [OpenGL Scale Single Pixel Line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654398/2521214)

Answer (score 2):

1. Render scene to low-resolution FBO.
2. Stretch-blit FBO contents to screen using a textured quad or `glBlitFramebuffer()`.