# How can I properly write this shader function in JS?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

#### What I want to happen:

For testing a game art style I thought of, I want to render a 3D world in pixel-art form. So for example, take a scene like this (but rendered with certain coloring / style so as to look good once pixelated):

[image: Original Image]

And make it look something like this:

[image: Pixelated Image]

By playing with different ways of styling the 3D source I think the pixelated output could look nice. Of course to get this effect one just sizes the image down to ~80p and upscales it to 1080p with nearest neighbor resampling. But it's more efficient to render straight to an 80p canvas to begin with and just do the upscaling.

This is not typically how one would use a shader, to resize a bitmap in nearest neighbor format, but the performance on it is better than any other way I've found to make such a conversion in real time.

#### My code:

My buffer for the bitmap is stored in row major, as `r1, g1, b1, a1, r2, g2, b2, a2...` and I'm using [gpu.js](https://github.com/gpujs/gpu.js) which essentially converts this JS func into a shader. My goal is to take one bitmap and return one at larger scale with nearest-neighbor scaling, so each pixel becomes a 2x2 square or 3x3 and so on. Assume `inputBuffer` is a scaled fraction of size of the output determined by the `setOutput` method.

```
var pixelateMatrix = gpu.createKernel(function(inputBuffer, width, height, scale) {
  var y = Math.floor((this.thread.x / (width[0] * 4)) / scale[0]);
  var x = Math.floor((this.thread.x % (width[0] * 4)) / scale[0]);
  var remainder = this.thread.x % 4;
  return inputBuffer[(x * y) + remainder]; 
}).setOutput([width * height * 4]);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31tw9nh3/)

> Keep in mind it's iterating over a new buffer of the full size output,
>   so I have to find the correct coordinates that will exist in the
>   smaller `sourceBuffer` based on the current index in the
>   `outputBuffer` (index is exposed by the lib as `this.thread.x`).

#### What's happening instead:

This, instead of making a nearest neighbor upscale, is making a nice little rainbow (above is the small normal render, below is the result of the shader, and to the right you can see some debug logging with stats about the input and output buffers):

[image: Result]

What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** I asked a related question here, [Is there a simpler (and still performant) way to upscale a canvas render with nearest neighbor resampling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440166/is-there-a-simpler-and-still-performant-way-to-upscale-a-canvas-render-with-ne/50468374#50468374)

Comment: I think you have the right idea, probably the simplest way to do this is draw to an offscreen canvas with your desired resolution. Then use webGL image filtering to upscale it to your display resolution.

Comment: @MrSmith yeah thats what I'm doing but my algorithm is wrong, thats the issue. I've reviewed it and its hard to debug because you cant use console logs inside the kernel func, and I cant seem to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: It may not be the best approach, I've left an answer on your other question about it.

Comment: @MrSmith will review that asap thanks

Comment: Np, do ask if there is any confusion. It might not be immediately clear how it can be used with an existing renderer.

Comment: see [OpenGL Scale Single Pixel Line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654398/2521214) which is the same thing you want to do using **OpenGL**

Comment: You have JSFiddle for your current code?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/31tw9nh3/

Comment: If anyone is wondering why my inputs into the shader func are used like arrays, it's because the lib converts that func into shaders and doesn't support normal variables as inputs, only arrays.

Comment: Update from @david in the chat with my own addition of a background color, which helps demonstrate that pixels are being lost (seeming to lose one "set" as in the width of an up-scaled pixel, for example an 8x8 chunk if the scale is 8, per one row causing a slanted look) with this approach, but its progress nonetheless: http://jsfiddle.net/31tw9nh3/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Answer

Tarun's answer helped me get to my final solution, so his bounty was well deserved, but I actually learned about a feature (graphical output paired with context sharing for direct buffer output to the render target) of gpu.js that allows for roughly 30x faster rendering, bringing the total time for shading *and* rendering the output from 30ms+ to ~1ms, and this is without an additional optimization I now know to be possible to send the array buffer to the GPU even faster, but I just didnt have any motivation to get the shading / rendering time down lower than 1ms.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
var gpu = new GPU({
  canvas,
  gl
});
var pixelateMatrix = gpu.createKernel(function(inputBuffer, width, scale, size, purity, div) {
    var subX = Math.floor(this.thread.x / scale[0]);
    var subY = Math.floor(this.thread.y / scale[0]);
    var subIndex = ((subX * 4) + (subY * width[0] * 4));
    var rIndex = subIndex;
    var gIndex = subIndex + 1;
    var bIndex = subIndex + 2;
    var r = ((inputBuffer[rIndex] * purity[0]) + inputBuffer[rIndex - 4] + inputBuffer[rIndex + 4]) / (div[0]);
    var g = ((inputBuffer[gIndex] * purity[0]) + inputBuffer[gIndex - 4] + inputBuffer[gIndex + 4]) / (div[0]);
    var b = ((inputBuffer[bIndex] * purity[0]) + inputBuffer[bIndex - 4] + inputBuffer[bIndex + 4]) / (div[0]);
    this.color(r / 255, g / 255, b / 255);
  }).setOutput([width, height]).setGraphical(true);
```

`inputBuffer` is simply the buffer retrieved via three.js's `readRenderTargetPixels` method.

```
renderer.render(scene, camera, rt);
renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(rt, 0, 0, smallWidth, smallHeight, frameBuffer);
pixelateMatrix(frameBuffer, [smallWidth], [scale], [size], [purity], [div]);
```

## Side Note

Can we just marvel for a moment about how much power WebGL brings to the browser? That's 8.2944 million **multi-operation** tasks carried out in just ~1ms. ~64 billion total maximum math ops per second for my shader by my count. That's insanity. Can that even be right? Is my math wrong on that? [I see nvidia's self driving AI is performing 24 trillion ops/s](https://gizmodo.com/nvidias-autonomous-car-computer-makes-24-trillion-deep-1751078739), so I guess these numbers on my 1060 are within the realm of possibility. It's just incredible though.

GPU.js does a just fantastic job of optimizing matrix operations to run on the GPU without the need for learning shader code, and the creator is extremely active on the project, responding to issues usually in a matter of hours. Highly recommend you guys give the lib a try. Especially awesome for machine learning throughput.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the update :-), would be great if you can add an updated JSFiddle as well

Answer (score 11):

**Update 1 - 25th May 2018**

I was able to resolve most of the issues. There were quite a few

1. The logic of transformation was wrong, also the data was coming flipped for some reason, so I flipped cols and rows to start from bottom right

   ```
   var pixelateMatrix = gpu.createKernel(function(inputBuffer, width, height, scale) {
   var size = width[0] * height[0] * 4;
   var current_index = Math.floor((size - this.thread.x)/4); 
   var row = Math.floor(current_index / (width[0] * scale[0]) );
   var col = Math.floor((current_index % width[0])/scale[0]);
   var index_old = Math.floor(row * (width[0] / scale[0])) + width[0] - col;
   var remainder = this.thread.x % 4;
   return inputBuffer[index_old * 4 + remainder];

   }).setOutput([width * height * 4]);
   ```
2. You were using width and height in floats, which I have changed to be calculated first and then scaled

   ```
   var smallWidth = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / scale);
   var smallHeight = Math.floor(window.innerHeight / scale);

   var width = smallWidth * scale;
   var height = smallHeight * scale;


   var rt = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(smallWidth, smallHeight);
   var frameBuffer = new Uint8Array(smallHeight * smallHeight * 4);
   var outputBuffer = new Uint8ClampedArray(width * height * 4);
   ```
3. The canvas size was set to while inner width and height, you need to set it to just the image width and height

   ```
   context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   canvas.width = width;
   canvas.height = height;
   ```

Below is the final JSFiddle for the same

https://jsfiddle.net/are5Lbw8/6/

Results:

[image: Working Upscale]

Final Code for reference

```
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
var scale = 4;
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
var smallWidth = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / scale);
var smallHeight = Math.floor(window.innerHeight / scale);

var width = smallWidth * scale;
var height = smallHeight * scale;


var rt = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(smallWidth, smallHeight);
var frameBuffer = new Uint8Array(smallHeight * smallHeight * 4);
var outputBuffer = new Uint8ClampedArray(width * height * 4);
var output;
var divisor = 2;
var divisorHalf = divisor / 2;
var negativeDivisorHalf = -1 * divisorHalf;
var canvas;
var context;
var gpu = new GPU();

var pixelateMatrix = gpu.createKernel(function(inputBuffer, width, height, scale) {
/*   var y = Math.floor((this.thread.x / (width[0] * 4)) / scale[0]);
  var x = Math.floor((this.thread.x % (width[0] * 4)) / scale[0]);
  var remainder = this.thread.x % 4;
  return inputBuffer[(x * y) + remainder];
   */
   var size = width[0] * height[0] * 4;
   var current_index = Math.floor((size - this.thread.x)/4); 
   var row = Math.floor(current_index / (width[0] * scale[0]) );
   var col = Math.floor((current_index % width[0])/scale[0]);
   var index_old = Math.floor(row * (width[0] / scale[0])) + width[0] - col;
   var remainder = this.thread.x % 4;
   return inputBuffer[index_old * 4 + remainder];

}).setOutput([width * height * 4]);
console.log(window.innerWidth);
console.log(window.innerHeight);
init();
animate();

function init() {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
  camera.position.z = 100;

  // scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xbbbbbb);
  scene.add(ambient);
  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xdddddd);
  directionalLight.position.set(0, 0, 1);
  scene.add(directionalLight);

  // texture
  var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
  manager.onProgress = function(item, loaded, total) {
    console.log(item, loaded, total);
  };
  var texture = new THREE.Texture();
  var onProgress = function(xhr) {
    if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
      var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
      console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
    }
  };
  var onError = function(xhr) {};
  var imgLoader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);
  imgLoader.load('https://i.imgur.com/P6158Su.jpg', function(image) {
    texture.image = image;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
  });

  // model
  var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
  objLoader.load('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/286022/Bulbasaur.obj', function(object) {
    object.traverse(function(child) {
      if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        child.material.map = texture;
      }
    });
    object.scale.x = 45;
    object.scale.y = 45;
    object.scale.z = 45;
    object.rotation.y = 3;
    object.position.y = -10.5;
    scene.add(object);
  }, onProgress, onError);
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true,
    antialias: false
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(smallWidth, smallHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  renderer.context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  renderer.context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  renderer.context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
  windowHalfX = (window.innerWidth / 2) / scale;
  windowHalfY = (window.innerHeight / 2) / scale;
  camera.aspect = (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight) / scale;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(smallWidth, smallHeight);
}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

  mouseX = (event.clientX - windowHalfX) / scale;
  mouseY = (event.clientY - windowHalfY) / scale;

}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

var flag = 0;

function render() {
  camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * .05;
  camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * .05;
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  renderer.render(scene, camera, rt);
  renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(rt, 0, 0, smallWidth, smallHeight, frameBuffer);
  //console.time('gpu');
  console.log(frameBuffer, [width], [height], [scale]);
  var outputBufferRaw = pixelateMatrix(frameBuffer, [width], [height], [scale]);
  //console.timeEnd('gpu');
  if (flag < 15) {
    console.log('source', frameBuffer);
    console.log('output', outputBufferRaw);

    var count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < frameBuffer.length; i++) {
      if (frameBuffer[i] != 0) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    console.log('source buffer length', frameBuffer.length)
    console.log('source non zero', count);

    var count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < outputBufferRaw.length; i++) {
      if (outputBufferRaw[i] != 0) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    console.log('output buffer length', outputBufferRaw.length)
    console.log('output non zero', count);
  }
  outputBuffer = new Uint8ClampedArray(outputBufferRaw);
  output = new ImageData(outputBuffer, width, height);
  context.putImageData(output, 0, 0);
  flag++;
}
```

**Original Answer**

I have gotten close but two issues are left

1. The image is getting inverted
2. Sometimes your `inputBuffer` size is not a multiple of 4, which causes it to misbehave.

Below is code I used

```
var pixelateMatrix = gpu.createKernel(function(inputBuffer, width, height, scale) {
   var current_index = Math.floor(this.thread.x/4); 
   var row = Math.floor(current_index / (width[0] * scale[0]) );
   var col = Math.floor((current_index % width[0])/scale[0]);
   var index_old = Math.floor(row * (width[0] / scale[0])) + col;
   var remainder = this.thread.x % 4;
   return inputBuffer[index_old * 4 + remainder];

}).setOutput([width * height * 4]);
```

Below is the JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/are5Lbw8/

And below is the current output

[image: Current State]

Comment: Yeah that's as far as @david got too and this is after I tinkered with it for about 2 hours: http://jsfiddle.net/31tw9nh3/10/

Comment: I noticed adding a certain value (depending on the screen width) like this can fix the slant but I havent been able to figure out how to fix it consistently across all screen sizes, or why that even works: `var inWidth = (width[0] / scale[0]) - 0.8;`

Comment: Also I have not been able to reproduce your claim that the inputBuffer size is not always a multiple of 4. I've been searching for any weird problem with the inputBuffer but it all looks good. The input buffer is simply grabbed from three.js's `renderer.readRenderTargetPixels` method.

Comment: @johndoe, please join this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171738/discussion-how-can-i-properly-write-this-shader-function-in-js-50518854) room

Answer (score 2):

I think the function should look like:

```
var pixelateMatrix = gpu.createKernel(function(inputBuffer, width, height, scale) {
    var x = Math.floor((this.thread.x / (width[0] * 4)) / scale[0]);
    var y = Math.floor((this.thread.x % (width[0] * 4)) / scale[0]);
    var finalval = y * (Math.floor(width[0]/scale[0]) * 4) + (x * 4);
    var remainder = this.thread.x % 4;
    return inputBuffer[finalval + remainder];
}).setOutput([width * height * 4]);
```

Basically, get x and y in similar manner as you, scale x and y, then converting back from (x,y) you multiple the y value by the new scaled width and add the x value. Not sure how you got x*y for that part of it.

Comment: Yea, it renders the bulbasaur, https://jsfiddle.net/31tw9nh3/2/ but on it's side. So something is still off

Comment: Then just flipping x and y should do it, if it's on its side.

Comment: So close. Flipping x and y toggles between sideways and upside down weirdly. I'll keep plsying with it. Therems a fiddle in the wuestion btw

Comment: In addition to being upside down or sideways (depending on flipping x and y) it also, when upside down, renders 4 copies of the model, and in both configurations the model its streched vertically by 100%. I rendered a square in the corner just to verify that it's the output, not the canvas, that's stretched.

Comment: An attempt by @david to fix it in the chat room, his has funny issues too, Ive been tinkering with it trying to make it work but not luck yet: http://jsfiddle.net/31tw9nh3/1/