# Rendering with pixelated effect in THREE.js

Tags: graphics, three.js, html5-canvas, webgl

I'm working on a THREE.js scene that I'd like to render with a pixelated effect. To do so, I'm using `renderer.setPixelRatio(...)` to draw the scene at a low resolution, which works fine. The problem is that the result seems to be antialiased, maybe even by the canvas' WebGL context.

In the Canvas 2d drawing api, one can set `canvas.context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;` to ensure that low-resolution scenes are drawn with a crisp pixelated effect. I tried using this parameter on my `renderer.context`, with no effect. Is there some other way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this? http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_pixel.html

Comment: If you can't find a Three.js solution. I've provided an answer to a similar question but in pure WebGL. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50468374/7614070

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with CSS stylesheets. Just add this line to the canvas style:

```
canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```