# Pixelating the OpenGL view

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want the view of OpenGL to be pixelated.

I have tried using multiple shaders from around the internet, which shows a pixelated image as their outcome. But they work on textures and not in 3D models (Their edges to be pixelated).

[This is what I have tried](http://coding-experiments.blogspot.com/2010/06/pixelation.html)

And this is a reference of what I am expecting:

[image: img]

Is there any way of accomplishing it with shaders, or with code?

**EDIT:**

I used `glFramebuffer` from Makogan's answer, and it seems to be pixelated.

But another problem is encountered. The Framebuffer seems to be copying itself, which eventually creates a mess.

[This is how it looks](https://i.imgur.com/XO9qVKL_d.webp?maxwidth=1520&fidelity=grand)

This code is what I used to create the Framebuffer:

```py
FBO = glGenFramebuffers(1)
DBO = glGenRenderbuffers(1)

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, DBO)
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 1280, 720)

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO)
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, DBO)
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
```

And this piece of code is in the main loop:

```py
# draw everything

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
    
glBlitFramebuffer(
        640 - 256,
        360 - 144,
        640 + 256,
        360 + 144,
        0,
        0,
        640,
        360,
        GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT,
        GL_NEAREST
)
```

Comment: see [OpenGL Scale Single Pixel Line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654398/2521214) so simply you render into texture and then scale the texture ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pixelate your output, just downscale the dimensions of the framebuffer you are rendering to to very small dimensions (say 256 x 256) and turn off all anti aliasing.

You will have 3D pixelated rendering.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I did some research on framebuffers and got it to work. Even though I am encountering a problem. The pixelated framebuffer is copying itself, as if it is repeating. How to fix that? Here is a picture: https://imgur.com/a/2FWa3yQ

Comment: That looks like you are not mapping the FB correctly to your viewport.

Comment: Yes. I am mapping the FB as `(0, 0, 640, 360)`, while the window is `(0, 0, 1920, 1080)`. I created a new question on this problem here (things are mode detailed there): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786701/low-resolution-framebuffer-repeats-itself#