# How to 2x screen pixels so each pixel is represented as 4 pixels in a square?

Tags: graphics, pixel, scaling, magnification

I don't know where to ask this question.

Is it possible to 2x or 4x pixels on the screen similar to how magnifying programs do, but they blur the pixels. I want sharp square pixels. Emulators for old games can do this easily. Is there a way to do this with a video player or magnifying program?

Scaling a video into a small size to create this effect doesn't work because the result is a horribly blurred image and scaling it back to a higher resolution works but the file size is gigantic and it takes a long time to render.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: "Is it possible to [create] 2x or 4x pixels on the screen similar to how magnifying programs do?"  I'm assuming by 2x you mean 2x2 and by 4x you mean 4x4.  Yes, it's possible.  Microsoft Paint does this.  You either have to write code or acquire code that does this.

Comment: how you render ?  with what api/lib ? see similar: [OpenGL Scale Single Pixel Line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654398/2521214)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get low resolution videos to play in crisp square pixels by changing the following setting in VLC player:
Tools > Preferences > Video > Output > Windows GDI Video Output

In other video players there might be a "scaling" setting that can be changed to "nearest neighbor" to get the same square pixels.