# Draw colored lines with different widths using VBOs?

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, colors, vbo

My goal is to render a list of segments using VBOs with different colors and if possible with different widths.

Each vertex is defined by:

```
class Vector2f {
public:
    float x, y;
};
```

The list of segments consists in pairs of vertexes that define a segment.

Then I initialize the VBO:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vector2f) * segments.size(), &segments[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

And then I draw using:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vector2f), (void*)(sizeof(float) * 0));
glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, segments.size());
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

In my example, I want to give to each segment a color. The color is previously defined and can only be 1 from 3 options.
How can I do it? And can I optimize it by using indexes for color instead of repeating them all over?

If so, how?

Also, is it possible to define the width of each individual segment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I do it?

Extend your vertex struct to contain color values:

```
class Vector2f
{
public:
    float x, y;
    unsigned char r, g, b;
};
```

And use `GL_COLOR_ARRAY` + `glColorPointer()`:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vector2f), offsetof( Vector2f, x ) );
glColorPointer(3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(Vector2f), offsetof( Vector2f, r ) );
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, segments.size());
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

> Also, is it possible to define the width of each individual segment?

Not really with fixed-function.  You either end up with a `glLineWidth()` + draw-call per segment (losing the performance benefit of batching draw-calls) or [converting the line into triangle geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3058978/44729) on the CPU (significantly more complicated).

Comment: So I cannot optimize the color array using indexes?

Comment: @gdf31: Not really, OpenGL doesn't allow for a separate index array for each attribute.

Comment: @gdf31: Honestly if you're targeting desktop OpenGL vertex data is just microscopic compared to even a handful of textures.

Comment: Can I have a std;;vector with the Vector2f of the position and then a Vector3f color and so on? How to deal with the strides in this case?

Comment: @gdf31: Yup, totally doable.  In that case you can use `0` for the `stride`s since your values are tightly-packed.